# Right-aligning text over expression

Tags: math-mode

Basically, I want something like this:

```
$$ \overset{\qquad\quad\; 2}{\sqrt{x+x^2}} $$
```

where the expression above is (automatically) right-aligned, but I have no idea how to achieve this. (The example above is manually spaced, I want it to be automatic.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Also, you should use `\[` ... `\]` instead of `$$` ... `$$`. See [Why is \\[ … \\] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 

\[
\overset{\hfill 2}{\sqrt{x+x^2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In modern LaTeX document you shouldn't use the TeX construct `$$...$$` but `\[...\]`. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) .

Comment: Under magnification, it would seem the alignment is not quite perfect.  Would you not agree?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I can only zoom at 400% (the attached image uses that factor), and I get the "2" flushed to the right. As I understood the question this was the OP's intent, although I see in your answer that you aligned the "2" with the superscript inside the radical. Whcih kind og alignment is desired by the OP, I cannot tell from the question. The OP will decide, I guess.

Comment: Good point.  I guess I assumed that he wanted the 2's aligned, but that is a presumption on my part.  May the best alignment win!

Comment: You can fix the alignment issue by adding `\mkern1mu` -- that's just one third of the width of `\thinspace` -- to the argument of `\overset`: `\overset{\hfill 2\mkern1mu}{\sqrt{x+x^2}}`. When viewed at 6400% magnification, the two `2` glyphs look perfectly aligned...

Comment: @Mico As they say, a `\kern` heals all wounds, or something like that.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Nicely put. :-) Not quite sure, though, if it's really a "wound"...

Answer (score 5):

With a stack, you can get the alignment of the two right `\scriptstyle` numbers, which is how I read the OP's question.  Perhaps that is a more constraining interpretation than the OP requested (Gonzalo interpreted "alignment" in a slightly different way).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\def\sqrtoverset#1#2{\ensurestackMath{%
  \def\stackalignment{r}\def\stacktype{L}\stackon[0pt]{%
    \def\stacktype{S}\stackon[1pt]{#1}{{}^{#2}}%
  }{\displaystyle\sqrt{\phantom{#1}}}%
}}
\[
\sqrtoverset{x+x^2}{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, my intention was not necessarily to align the 2's, only the expressions as a whole. (The fact that there even was a superscript 2 under the radical was just coincidental.) Besides, since I did not have the `stackengine` package and didn't bother to install it either, this was the easiest answer for me. But thanks anyways :)

Comment: @Frxstrem No problem.  Glad you got a suitable answer.